# PHP accessing data from an Object

Tags: php

I fill up an array, and when I output the following

```
var_dump($users["JohnDoe"]);
```

I see something like the following

```
adLDAPUserCollection {#348 ▼
  #adldap: adLDAP {#287 ▶}
  #currentObject: null
  #info: array:2 [▼
    "count" => 1
    0 => array:17 [▼
      "telephonenumber" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "123456789"
      ]
      0 => "telephonenumber"
      "displayname" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "John Doe"
      ]
      1 => "displayname"
      "department" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "Some Department"
      ]
      2 => "department"
      "primarygroupid" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "123"
      ]
      3 => "primarygroupid"
      "objectsid" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => b"\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x"
      ]
      4 => "objectsid"
      "samaccountname" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "JohnDoe"
      ]
      5 => "samaccountname"
      "mail" => array:2 [▼
        "count" => 1
        0 => "JohnDoe@email.com"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is get the department of the user.  When I try the following

```
var_dump($users["JohnDoe"]->info[0]["department"][0]);
```

I am returned null.  How can I get this users department?

Thanks

Comment: could you add the raw json object?

Comment: Exactly what is `$users`? An array of instances of [this](https://github.com/munkireport/munkireport-php/blob/master/app/lib/adLDAP/collections/adLDAPUserCollection.php)?

Comment: I think so - originally it comes from this https://github.com/SaschaDens/ldap-connector

Comment: Then I guess it's just `$users['JohnDoe']['telephonenumber']`.  If that doesn't work, please [provide](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35150101/edit) the output of `var_export($users['JohnDoe'])` (instead of the fancied-up var_dump).